# How can I open vlc with a URL scheme

Tags: swift, xcode, vlc

How can I open vlc with URL scheme?
I currently have a video file stored locally with the name video and I receive an error:

```
         "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

The Code

```
           let vlcURL = "vlc://video.mp4"
           let vlcItem = ("vlc", URL(string:vlcURL)!)  //i recive the error her

          var installedvideoApps = [("Vlc", URL(string:vlcURL)!)]

           if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(vlcItem.1) {
               installedvideoApps.append(vlcItem)
           }

           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Selection", message: "Select Video App",   
           preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

           for app in installedvideoApps {
               let button = UIAlertAction(title: app.0, style: .default, handler: { _ in
                   UIApplication.shared.open(app.1, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
               })
               alert.addAction(button)
           }
           let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
           alert.addAction(cancel)
           present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when running this code.

Comment: @Frankenstein not after running the code after pressing the button

Comment: @Frankenstein Just tried it in another project and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding encoding to the `URL` with `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`.

```
let vlcURL = "vlc://video.mp4".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
let vlcItem = ("vlc", URL(string:vlcURL)!)
```

Comment: Can you help me with the URL scheme it dosnt play the video and i dont know why

Comment: I'm not an expert on vlc's url schemes but, I'll try to help.

Comment: I just replaced video.mp4 with a stream URL "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4" And it worked but I have the video saved locally and thats what is left for me to figure this out